# Power BI - Legend based on measure value

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, visualization

I am representing on a map visualisation the 'gross margin' at different locations.  This may be positive, negative or (effectively) zero.  To represent this in the map I can use the Absolute value for the size and the Sign ("Positive"/"Negative"/"Nil") for the legend / colour. However I cannot use the dynamic Measure of Sign as a legend in the Map view.  It does not allow Measures in this feature.

There are many different ways of slicing the data, by product, by market, by time etc. to visualise where this selection is resulting in a positive or negative margin and an indication of the magnitude.

I cannot pre-calculate a column for every possible selection combination (pretty much uncountable).

Anyone know of a way to get around this limitation?

The image below shows a related example comparing two scenarios and showing "Closed"/"Down"/"Unchanged"/"Up". It currently uses a calculated column on two preselected scenarios, and does not take account of product or timeline filtering - so is often misleading.

[image: Map visualisation of difference between two data sets, with the Legend/colour to be set according to a Measure]